# @foreach inside of @include

Tags: php, laravel

I want to add my slider to my home page and when i add using @inclued method and it returns error undefended variable in slider page but it works well in slider page however i added it to home page error occurs. how do i correct this.

error msg-

Undefined variable $data (View: \resources\views\frontendslider.blade.php)
In the: \resources\views/frontendslider.blade.php file at line: 29

codes....

homepage

```
 * LaraClassifier - Classified Ads Web Application
 * Copyright (c) BeDigit. All Rights Reserved
 *
 * Website: https://laraclassifier.com
 *
 * LICENSE
 * -------
 * This software is furnished under a license and may be used and copied
 * only in accordance with the terms of such license and with the inclusion
 * of the above copyright notice. If you Purchased from CodeCanyon,
 * Please read the full License from here - http://codecanyon.net/licenses/standard
--}}
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('search')
    @parent
    @includeFirst([config('larapen.core.customizedViewPath') . 'search.inc.form', 'search.inc.form'])
@endsection

@section('content')
    <div class="main-container">
        
        @includeFirst([config('larapen.core.customizedViewPath') . 'search.inc.breadcrumbs', 'search.inc.breadcrumbs'])
        
        @if (config('settings.list.show_cats_in_top'))
            @if (isset($cats) && $cats->count() > 0)
                <div class="container mb-2 hide-xs">
                    <div class="row p-0 m-0">
                        <div class="col-12 p-0 m-0 border border-bottom-0 bg-light"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            @endif
            @includeFirst([config('larapen.core.customizedViewPath') . 'search.inc.categories', 'search.inc.categories'])
        @endif
        
        <?php if (isset($topAdvertising) && !empty($topAdvertising)): ?>
            @includeFirst([config('larapen.core.customizedViewPath') . 'layouts.inc.advertising.top', 'layouts.inc.advertising.top'], ['paddingTopExists' => true])
        <?php
            $paddingTopExists = false;
        else:
            if (isset($paddingTopExists) && $paddingTopExists) {
                $paddingTopExists = false;
            }
        endif;
        ?>
        
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">

                {{-- Sidebar --}}
                @if (config('settings.list.left_sidebar'))
                    @includeFirst([config('larapen.core.customizedViewPath') . 'search.inc.sidebar', 'search.inc.sidebar'])
                    <?php $contentColSm = 'col-md-9'; ?>
                @else
                    <?php $contentColSm = 'col-md-12'; ?>
                @endif

                {{-- Content --}}
                <div class="{{ $contentColSm }} page-content col-thin-left mb-4">
                    <div class="category-list {{ config('settings.list.display_mode', 'make-grid') }}{{ ($contentColSm == 'col-md-12') ? ' noSideBar' : '' }}">
                        <div class="tab-box">

                            {{-- Nav tabs --}}
                            <ul id="postType" class="nav nav-tabs add-tabs tablist" role="tablist">
                                <?php
                                $aClass = '';
                                $spanClass = 'alert-danger';
                                if (config('settings.single.show_listing_types')) {
                                    if (!request()->filled('type') || request()->get('type') == '') {
                                        $aClass = ' active';
                                        $spanClass = 'bg-danger';
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    $aClass = ' active';
                                    $spanClass = 'bg-danger';
                                }
                                ?>
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a href="{!! qsUrl(request()->url(), request()->except(['page', 'type']), null, false) !!}" class="nav-link{{ $aClass }}">
                                        {{ t('All Listings') }} <span class="badge badge-pill {!! $spanClass !!}">{{ $count->get('all') }}</span>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                @if (config('settings.single.show_listing_types'))
                                    @if (isset($postTypes) && $postTypes->count() > 0)
                                        @foreach ($postTypes as $postType)
                                            <?php
                                                $postTypeUrl = qsUrl(
                                                    request()->url(),
                                                    array_merge(request()->except(['page']), ['type' => $postType->id]),
                                                    null,
                                                    false
                                                );
                                                $postTypeCount = ($count->has($postType->id)) ? $count->get($postType->id) : 0;
                                            ?>
                                            @if (request()->filled('type') && request()->get('type') == $postType->id)
                                                <li class="nav-item">
                                                    <a href="{!! $postTypeUrl !!}" class="nav-link active">
                                                        {{ $postType->name }}
                                                        <span class="badge badge-pill bg-danger">
                                                            {{ $postTypeCount }}
                                                        </span>
                                                    </a>
                                                </li>
                                            @else
                                                <li class="nav-item">
                                                    <a href="{!! $postTypeUrl !!}" class="nav-link">
                                                        {{ $postType->name }}
                                                        <span class="badge badge-pill alert-danger">
                                                            {{ $postTypeCount }}
                                                        </span>
                                                    </a>
                                                </li>
                                            @endif
                                        @endforeach
                                    @endif
                                @endif
                            </ul>
                            
                            <div class="tab-filter pb-2">
                                {{-- OrderBy Desktop --}}
                                <select id="orderBy" title="sort by" class="niceselecter select-sort-by small" data-style="btn-select" data-width="auto">
                                    @if (isset($orderByArray) && !empty($orderByArray))
                                        @foreach($orderByArray as $option)
                                            @if ($option['condition'])
                                                <option{{ $option['isSelected'] ? ' selected="selected"' : '' }} value="{!! $option['url'] !!}">
                                                    {{ $option['label'] }}
                                                </option>
                                            @endif
                                        @endforeach
                                    @endif
                                </select>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="listing-filter">
                            <div class="float-start col-md-9 col-sm-8 col-12">
                                <h1 class="h6 pb-0 breadcrumb-list">
                                    {!! (isset($htmlTitle)) ? $htmlTitle : '' !!}
                                </h1>
                                <div style="clear:both;"></div>
                            </div>
                            
                            {{-- Display Modes --}}
                            @if (isset($posts) && $posts->count() > 0)
                                <?php $currDisplay = config('settings.list.display_mode'); ?>
                                <div class="float-end col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-12 text-end listing-view-action">
                                    @if (isset($displayModesArray) && !empty($displayModesArray))
                                        @foreach($displayModesArray as $displayMode => $value)
                                            <span class="grid-view{{ ($currDisplay == $displayMode) ? ' active' : '' }}">
                                                @if ($currDisplay == $displayMode)
                                                    <i class="fas fa-th-large"></i>
                                                @else
                                                    <a href="{!! $value['url'] !!}">
                                                        <i class="{{ $value['icon'] }}"></i>
                                                    </a>
                                                @endif
                                            </span>
                                        @endforeach
                                    @endif
                                </div>
                            @endif
                            
                            <div style="clear:both"></div>
                        </div>
                        
                        {{-- Mobile Filter Bar --}}
                        <div class="mobile-filter-bar col-xl-12">
                            <ul class="list-unstyled list-inline no-margin no-padding">
                                @if (config('settings.list.left_sidebar'))
                                    <li class="filter-toggle">
                                        <a class=""><i class="fas fa-bars"></i> {{ t('Filters') }}</a>
                                    </li>
                                @endif
                                <li>
                                    {{-- OrderBy Mobile --}}
                                    <div class="dropdown">
                                        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown">{{ t('Sort by') }}</a>
                                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                            @if (isset($orderByArray) && !empty($orderByArray))
                                                @foreach($orderByArray as $option)
                                                    @if ($option['condition'])
                                                        <li><a href="{!! $option['url'] !!}" rel="nofollow">{{ $option['label'] }}</a></li>
                                                    @endif
                                                @endforeach
                                            @endif
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="menu-overly-mask"></div>
                        {{-- Mobile Filter bar End--}}
                        
                        <div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
                            <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="contentAll" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="tabAll">
                                <div id="postsList" class="category-list-wrapper posts-wrapper row no-margin">
                                    <div class="slider">
                                        @include('frontendslider')
                                    </div>
                                    @if (config('settings.list.display_mode') == 'make-list')
                                        @includeFirst([config('larapen.core.customizedViewPath') . 'search.inc.posts.template.list', 'search.inc.posts.template.list'])
                                    @elseif (config('settings.list.display_mode') == 'make-compact')
                                        @includeFirst([config('larapen.core.customizedViewPath') . 'search.inc.posts.template.compact', 'search.inc.posts.template.compact'])
                                    @else
                                        @includeFirst([config('larapen.core.customizedViewPath') . 'search.inc.posts.template.grid', 'search.inc.posts.template.grid'])
                                    @endif
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="tab-box save-search-bar text-center">
                            @if (request()->filled('q') && request()->get('q') != '' && $count->get('all') > 0)
                                <a id="saveSearch"
                                   data-name="{!! qsUrl(request()->url(), request()->except(['_token', 'location']), null, false) !!}"
                                   data-count="{{ $count->get('all') }}"
                                >
                                    <i class="far fa-bell"></i> {{ t('Save Search') }}
                                </a>
                            @else
                                <a href="#"> &nbsp; </a>
                            @endif
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    
                    @if ($posts->hasPages())
                        <nav class="mt-3 mb-0 pagination-sm" aria-label="">
                            {!! $posts->appends(request()->query())->links() !!}
                        </nav>
                    @endif
                    
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        {{-- Advertising --}}
        @includeFirst([config('larapen.core.customizedViewPath') . 'layouts.inc.advertising.bottom', 'layouts.inc.advertising.bottom'])
        
        {{-- Promo Listing Button --}}
        <div class="container mb-3">
            <div class="card border-light text-dark bg-light mb-3">
                <div class="card-body text-center">
                    <h2>{{ t('do_you_have_anything') }}</h2>
                    <h5>{{ t('sell_products_and_services_online_for_free') }}</h5>
                    @if (!auth()->check() && config('settings.single.guests_can_post_listings') != '1')
                        <a href="#quickLogin" class="btn btn-border btn-post btn-listing" data-bs-toggle="modal">{{ t('start_now') }}</a>
                    @else
                        <a href="{{ \App\Helpers\UrlGen::addPost() }}" class="btn btn-border btn-post btn-listing">{{ t('start_now') }}</a>
                    @endif
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        {{-- Category Description --}}
        @if (isset($cat, $cat->description) && !empty($cat->description))
            @if (!(bool)$cat->hide_description)
                <div class="container mb-3">
                    <div class="card border-light text-dark bg-light mb-3">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            {!! $cat->description !!}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            @endif
        @endif
        
        {{-- Show Posts Tags --}}
        @if (config('settings.list.show_listings_tags'))
            @if (isset($tags) && !empty($tags))
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="card mb-3">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h2 class="card-title"><i class="fas fa-tags"></i> {{ t('Tags') }}:</h2>
                            @foreach($tags as $iTag)
                                <span class="d-inline-block border border-inverse bg-light rounded-1 py-1 px-2 my-1 me-1">
                                    <a href="{{ \App\Helpers\UrlGen::tag($iTag) }}">
                                        {{ $iTag }}
                                    </a>
                                </span>
                            @endforeach
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            @endif
        @endif
        
    </div>
@endsection

@section('modal_location')
    @includeFirst([config('larapen.core.customizedViewPath') . 'layouts.inc.modal.location', 'layouts.inc.modal.location'])
@endsection

@section('after_scripts')
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#postType a').click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var goToUrl = $(this).attr('href');
                redirect(goToUrl);
            });
            $('#orderBy').change(function () {
                var goToUrl = $(this).val();
                redirect(goToUrl);
            });
        });
    </script>
@endsection
```

controller

```
        public function frontendslider(Request $request){

        $data=slider::all();

        return view('frontendslider',compact('data'));
    }

    public function frontendslider2(Request $request){

        $data=slider::all();

        return view('return',compact('data'));
    }
```

web.php

```
Route::get('frontendslider',[App\Http\Controllers\Admin\SliderController::class,'frontendslider']);

Route::get('return',[App\Http\Controllers\Admin\SliderController::class,'frontendslider2']);
```

Comment: You need to pass the slider data to the homepage view - its no use creating a separate route for the slider because it will never be called.

Comment: @Snapey Thanks buddy but it's not working I tried it.

Answer (score -1):

Anyone face like this kind of issue specelly working with lara classifers use this before your importing page or page that content update..

```
@php
 $data=DB::table('slider')->get();
@endphp
```

PLS note input your data to $data and table name!!!!

Comment: You should do this in the controller...  This is NOT a good solution.

Comment: It's bad practice, don't fetch data from the database in the blade template

Comment: @Lk77 then how i fix that error!!!!

Comment: you should pass data along from the controller to the view, and add data to extend `@extends('view', ['data' => $data])`

Comment: or in your case `@include('frontendslider', ['data' => $data])`, you should fetch the data in your homepage controller and pass it to homepage view, which in turn pass it to frontendslider view